# How do I write async/await code without chaining and nesting a bunch of promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm struggling with this one quite a bit.

Let's say for example, I need a value before I can do other work.

To retrieve the value, I need to make an API call.

In my normal programming brain, I want to do this:

```
let x = api.getLocationOfUser('user154');
```

Followed by other code such as:

```
let y = geo.getTaxRulesByLocationId(x.location_id);
```

Is the only way to achieve this through nesting?

Comment: As your title says, use `await`..? `let x = await api...` (make sure it returns a consumable `Promise`) If that doesn't work, can you post your current code (or example code) that has too much nesting so we can see what you're dealing with?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are facing a problem called *CallbackHell*.

```
function myfunc() {
    otherFunctionThatReturnsPromise.then((a) => {
        otherFunction(a).then((b) => {
            // Do stuff
            console.log(b);
        });
    });
}
```

Try the following code:

```
async function myfunc() {

   let a = await otherFunctionThatReturnsPromise();

   // This line wont be executed until the upper line returns with a resolved Promise
   let b = await otherFunction(a);
}
```

For reference take a look to [the MDN site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)