# Handle Node Request response in nested requests

Tags: node.js, request-promise

Below is the pseudo code for my program

```
1. Call a webservice which returns a json response 
2. Parse it to get an id
3. Use the above id to call a different url to get more information
4. the above request return a list of items in json format
5. I am using the above items to call another webservice to get information specific to these items
6. I am making a custom json to concatenate the json for all these items
7. I can see the required format in my console.
```

Problem 
The response is sent to the client even before the json has been constructed/processed. As per search on google I am using 'request-promise-native' module.

Below is the snippet of my code.

```
var json ={}
var jsonkey='templates';


        var optionsrp1 = {
        url:''
        header:''
        }
        rp1(options)
            .then(function (body) {
        // this return id
                rp2(options1)
            .then(function (body) {
        // use the id to get items

                rp3(options2)
            .then(function (body) {
                body.value.foreach() {
                   rp4(optionx).then(){
                      json.key.....
                       .........



             }
                res.send(jsonresponse)------------> this statement sends response without even waiting for the loop to finish. I am sure the change has to be in the above loop to trigger a promise for each request but not sure how to attain it. The number of items is dynamic.
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                // API call failed...
            });
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                // API call failed...
            });
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                // API call failed...
            });

any help or pointers will be appreciated
```

Comment: You might consider indenting your code properly, it'll make it a lot easier to read and debug when you can tell at a glance where the blocks are.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Have no clue how to do it

Comment: Post the code you're using.  What you've given is not your code you're using.  The code doesn't even run do to invalid code blocks, improper comments, etc.

Comment: i have hand written this code as my code is on my dev machine and cant be copied over.Will try to fix it as much as I can

Comment: Any decent syntax-aware editor will have some sort of Tidy option, including the one here on SO itself

Comment: Maybe using `Promise.All`, and also consider refactor you code to use `async/await` pattern, you are in a _callback hell_

Comment: @JuanDM Any example/sample code which I can follow for async/await?

Comment: @user3509208 take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52827183/2860519

Comment: Resolved it Thanks @JuanDM

Comment: @user3509208, Put your answer here to help others !!.. if the answer in the provided link helped you upvote it ;)..

Comment: Cant post my answer but used promise.all along with request-promise-native to dynamically create one for each item in my returned json.